# Athlon 64 4000+ rapidly heats to 70° after power up

Tags: cooling, temperature, amd-athlon

Is it normal that my A64 4000+ AMD CPU rapidly heats up to 70+ degrees Celsius? It is visible in the BIOS config, and in a Windows tool.

I do not know the exact data it used to run, but I had problems with the mainboard/CPU combo, and the MSI guys recommended me to reseat it. That went OK I think, the relatively huge Zalman cooler above the CPU is blowing almost cold air, the system works perfectly, for as much I can test.

I did saw some tiny marks on the socket, which seemed to me like burn damage (the socket's "white", and about 4 holes for the pins do look a little brown. They didn't melt, but it worries me.

So basically: is this CPU meant to be screwed? Are those temps normal (it were a few hot days, temp of the living room gets up to 25°C-27°C) ? What can I do to fix this if it's not normal.

The CPU cooler is attached securely (it is not loose), and the cooling paste was reused when reseated (same cooler, same CPU), and I did not loose to much, only a tiny bit stayed on my fingers, and compared to the other CPU's I've seen, there was more than enough.

Comment: My A64 4000+ reaches 50C with the original cooler.

Comment: http://www.cpu-world.com/CPUs/K8/AMD-Athlon%2064%20X2%204000+%20-%20ADO4000IAA5DD%20%28ADO4000DDBOX%29.html

Answer (score 1):

**Don't panic**. CPUs can take 70°C for a while.

Cooling paste is **not** meant to be reused, and what is left on cooler and CPU now has probably the opposite effect.

When you reseat a CPU (-cooler) you remove the cooling paste or pad completely. I use [Isopropyl alcohol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isopropyl_alcohol) as cleaning fluid.

Then you apply a small amount of new cooling paste and reattach the cooler.